# Exercício bubble sort em C usando matriz com nomes

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, bubblesort

Olá, pessoal. Estou realizando um exercício na **linguagem C** utilizando a estrutura de dados chamada *bubble sort*. 
Basicamente, o exercício pede para eu ordernar essa quantidade de nomes em ordem crescente (com *bubble sort*): 
 **[Miriam, Sueli, Ana, Miguel, Daniel, Tales, Humberto]**.  
 
Então, fiz uma matriz para armazenar os 7 nomes (com 7 linhas e 8 colunas, pois o maior nome dentre os escolhidos possui 8 caracteres) e utilizei ela na função bsort que criei. Nesta função, utilizei alguns comandos da biblioteca string.h para poder manipular textos. 
 
**Agora vem o problema**, que sinceramente não sei o porque acontece, mas uma linha da matriz, aparentemente, parece estar juntando com outra linha. Pelo que percebi, pode ser algo relacionado a minha função ou a forma que criei a matriz. Por isso, peço ajuda para poderem me explicar o erro e como posso consertá-lo:
( Este é o código feito ↓ )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int quantidadeNomes = 7;
char matrizNomes[7][8] = {"Miriam", "Sueli", "Ana", "Miguel", "Daniel", "Tales", "Humberto"}; 

void bsort () {
    
    int validacao, quantidadeRepeticoes = 1;
    
    char matrizAuxiliar[8];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < quantidadeNomes; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (quantidadeNomes - quantidadeRepeticoes); j++) {
            
            validacao = strcmp(matrizNomes[j], matrizNomes[j+1]);
            // 0 = igual | -1 = primeiro menor que segundo | 1 = primeiro maior que segundo
            
            if (validacao > 0) {
            
                strcpy(matrizAuxiliar, matrizNomes[j]);
            
                strcpy(matrizNomes[j], matrizNomes[j+1]);
            
                strcpy(matrizNomes[j+1], matrizAuxiliar);
            }
        }
        quantidadeRepeticoes++;
    }
    
}

int main()
{
    
    printf("Ordem dos nomes antes do bsort: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("%s | ", matrizNomes[i]);
    }
    
    printf("\n\n");

    bsort();
    
    printf("Ordem dos nomes depois do bsort: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("%s | ", matrizNomes[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Eu utilizei o main (função principal) apenas para fazer um laço for mostrando a matriz antes do bsort e depois do bsort. Se executou o código, pôde ver que a saída é semelhante a esta aqui: 
[Saída do código atual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhRKy.png)

Porém, a saída esperada seria esta: 
[Saída esperada](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNyEX.png)

Eu fiz algo e acho que posso chamar de debug: Todas as vezes que faço a troca no espaço da matriz, o espaço onde se encontra Humberto está juntando com os caractesres do outro espaço trocado. Isso eu não entendo o porque está acontecendo e porque isso não aconteceu com os outros espaços da matriz.

Comment: só trocar **8** por **9**. sua matriz é militada por linha e coluna,  todos os nomes tem uma quantidade abaixo de 8 caracteres menos o **Humberto** que tem 9... **9** pq começa a contar a partir do **zero** então **Humberto** não si encaixa no tamanho da sua matriz.... **Humberto**  e qualquer nome maior que  `char matrizNomes[7][8]`  então para resolver aumente o tamanho `char matrizNomes[7][9]` acontecera a mesma coisa se por nomes maior que **Humberto**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
warning C4295: 'matrizNomes': array is too small to include a terminating null character
```

Seu compilador deve ter te avisado sobre isso com uma mensagem parecida. E o erro depois deveria ter te alertado. "Humberto" tem 8 letras e mais o terminador `\0` são 9. Não tem lugar no vetor para 9. Uma string vai até o próximo '\0' e não tinha lugar para um nesse caso e assim emendou com o que tinha depois

Podia ter declarado o simples

```
char matrizNomes[][9] = {
    "Miriam",
    "Sueli",
    "Ana",
    "Miguel",
    "Daniel",
    "Tales",
    "Humberto"
};
```

Quase *off-topic*

- *bubble sort* não é uma estrutura de dados. É um algoritmo
- `string.h` não tem comandos. Os cabeçalhos tem funções e nomes
- evite void
- não use nada global
- não copie código: use uma função para mostrar a matriz ao invés de fazer duas vezes a mesma coisa